# CSS class "macro"

Tags: css, macros, separation-of-concerns

I am a web front-end developer (newbie).

Hypothetically, if I am writing code for a web page using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and want a responsive sidebar, I can do something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">...</div>
```

Let's say, in the interest of separation of concerns, I would like the design people to decide how many columns wide the sidebar should be on each screen width.

Wouldn't it be better to do something like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">...</div>
```

and have the designer do something like this:

```
sidebar = col-xs-12 col-md-3
```

somewhere in the CSS?

Is this possible? Are there tools that will allow this? Am I way off base?

Comment: why would it be better?

Comment: Separation of concerns. As a developer I should not care how many columns wide the sidebar is. That is the designer's prerogative.

Comment: I think you should. As you are developting the HTML, you should know how many col it requieres?

Comment: Besides, using a class `sidebar` is even more declarative -- I'm not saying anything about how it should be displayed. I just saying what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a preprocesor to compile your CSS, and create semantic class from unit classes.

For example in [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
.sidebar {
    @extends .col-xs-12;
    @extends .col-md-3;
}
```

You can download Bootstrap in Sass on [the offical website](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download).

You can read the article ["Using Sass To Semantically @extend Bootstrap"](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/), it can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I'll take a look at SASS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, with some help from a [CSS preprocessor](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/preprocessors/) like the following:

- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

  - `.sidebar {
        @extends .col-xs-12;
        @extends .col-md-3;
    }`
- [Less](http://lesscss.org/)

  - `.sidebar {
       &:extend(.col-xs-12);
       &:extend(.col-md-3);
    }`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was guessing that this would be the answer. I'll need to investigate.

Comment: Both are very similar to Vanilla CSS, which makes them easy to use for just that one thing you need, or if you want to go pro, invest some time and learn how to properly use them @Ralph

Answer (score 1):

You propose instead of determining it in the html with a class on div like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">...</div>
```

determine it in the css with something like this:

```
.sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) and (max-width: $screen-sm-max) {
    width: 50%;
  }
  @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

In any case you have to edit something: either html file or css file. Consider your project, to know which one is easier.

I would suggest to put columns into the html (it would be kind of default case)

```
<div class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-md-3">...</div>
```

and then, if needed, override it for specific pages in css with something like this:

```
.page-order .sidebar {
     width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: I am hoping that my designer only needs to deal with the CSS and not mess with the HTML.